# No output on calling PHP function from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I want to call a PHP function from JavaScript.

I am calling the PHP function by passing two arguments and I want that PHP function to simply echo those arguments. For that, I have written the following code but it is not working, meaning that the code prints nothing. Please help.

JavaScript

```
jQuery.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    url: 'save.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {functionname:'saveUser', arguments:[username, password]},

    success: function (obj, textstatus) {
        if( !('error' in obj) ) {
            alert(obj.result);
        }
        else {
            console.log(obj.error);
        }
    }
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');   
    $aResult="done";

    if( $_POST['functionname'] == 'saveUser' ) {

        echo $_POST['arguments'][0] +" "+ $_POST['arguments'][1];
        echo json_encode($aResult);
    }
?>
```

Comment: What is output of `json_encode($aResult);` ? PHP file is not sending valid `json` either..

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, `echo $_POST['arguments'][0] +" "+ $_POST['arguments'][1];
        echo json_encode($aResult);` will not return valid json I suppose. Only `echo json_encode($aResult);` would do..

Comment: `+` is being used to concatenate.. Use `.`

Comment: Try just `console.log(obj);` as the first line in your `success` function. Should help you find more errors. Or make It really easy and check the network panel on the dev tools in your browser

Comment: @RayonDabre: I just saw your comment about `.`. If you'd like, I can remove my answer so you can post that as an answer. (I don't do PHP much, was off figuring out why it wasn't working.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, Not at all.. Your answer seems more precise to me. `exit();` after `json_encode` would be helpful just add a `full-stop`. Also wrap keys with `'` or `"`

Comment: @RayonDabre: Thanks. No need for wrapping the keys, `json_encode` does it. (I ran the code before posting it.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, May be you have disabled Notices, It says `Notice: Use of undefined constant arg0`

Comment: @RayonDabre: I'm just using a boring old PHP install. I get back the keys I used. But [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) uses strings, so I'll add them back.

Comment: I have updated my question please see and test it now, it is not working for me

Comment: @AliSalman: No, that's not how SO works. You can't edit the question such that it completely invalidates the answers you've received. The code in my answer **works**. If you're having trouble running it in your environment, that means something *else* is wrong, not that this question wasn't answered. You can ask a new question, but you'll need to include more information, since posting working code and saying it doesn't work isn't useful (we wouldn't be able to answer it).

Answer (score 3):

By using `+`, you're trying to convert the arguments to numbers and add them together. For string concatenation, you'd want `.` instead of `+`:

```
echo $_POST['arguments'][0] . " " . $_POST['arguments'][1];
```

But as Rayon [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34478610/no-output-on-calling-php-function-from-javascript/34478681#comment56698885_34478610) in the comments, you'll get invalid JSON as a result.

The following accesses the arguments just fine, and returns JSON:

```
<?php

    header('Content-Type: application/json');   
    $aResult="done";


    if( $_POST['functionname'] == 'saveUser' ) {

        echo json_encode(Array(
            'arg0' => $_POST['arguments'][0],
            'arg1' => $_POST['arguments'][1],
            'message' => $aResult
        ));
    }
?>
```

Of course, your JavaScript isn't looking for those property names. This would alert the name using your current JavaScript:

```
<?php

    header('Content-Type: application/json');   

    if( $_POST['functionname'] == 'saveUser' ) {

        echo json_encode(Array(
            'result' => $_POST['arguments'][0] . ' ' . $_POST['arguments'][1]
        ));
    }
?>
```

Comment: @AliSalman: It works at this end (I tried it before posting it, with your ajax code). Of course, the JavaScript alerts `undefined` because what I'm sending back isn't what it's looking for. But the keys are easily changed. I've added another block that sends back the arguments, concatenated, as `result` so it's alerted by your JavaScript code.

Comment: Yes it will work u just need to change your java script ajax success response if u r using firefox check console error in firebug

Comment: @devpro: The above works without any JavaScript changes.

Comment: Yes my brother its definitely work. I have also test by using thw same way +1

Comment: I have updated my question please see and test it now, it is not working for me

Comment: @AliSalman: The above works. If you're having trouble running it, you'll need to post a *new* question with enough detail to let us help you. *This* question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your php:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json'); 
$aResult="done";

 if( $_POST['functionname'] == 'saveUser' ) {
 echo $_POST['arguments'][0] +" "+ $_POST['arguments'][1];

 echo json_encode(array('result'=>$aResult)); 

}
```

You are using alert in ajax success by using obj.result. so I have used array in json_encode function with result index.

The value that you are echo in json_encode php this value you can get in ajax success.

Use console log like

```
console.log(obj);
```

You will get the response in obj.

Comment: @ali-salman: check console.log( obj); in ist line of ajax success